# Perpendicular tangent of polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Prove that any polynomial has a point such that there is no other point at which the tangents would be perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

If It has some optimum, the tangent at them in parallel to $x$-axis and only the tangents at infinity are perpendicular to it, that weren't real points.

If it hasn't any optimum, so it has a horizontal inflection point, that has tangent parallel to $x$-axis and only the tangents at infinity are perpendicular to it, that weren't real points.

Comment: Since the number of roots of drive is finite, so always the number of such points is finite too.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is constant or linear, all the tangents are the same. So assume $\deg f\ge 2$.

Since $f'$ is continuous, there are two possibilities:

1. If $f'$ has some root $a$ then the tangent at this point is horizontal, and no tangent can be vertical.
2. If $f'$ has no root, it has constant sign, so no two tangents to $f$ can be perpendicular.